# Macros in Clojure, evaluation and quoting

Tags: macros, clojure, lisp, compojure

I'm trying to write a macro to conditionally wrap `compojure` handler in a middleware only in certain environments. I seem to be lost in the evaluation order and what/how should I quote. My current attempt is as follows:

```clojure
(defn empty-middleware [handler]
  (fn [request] (handler request)))

(defmacro prod [handler middleware]
  (if (= "production" (System/getenv "APP_ENV"))
    (middleware handler)
    (empty-middleware handler)))
```

Desired usage is:

```
(in/prod (fn [handler]  (airbrake/wrap-airbrake handler config/airbrake-api-key)))
```

--- EDIT ---

Some more information:
in/prod is supposed to be used inside threading macro that wraps routes in a number of middlewares like:

```
(-> handler
    middleware1
    middleware2
    (in/prod (middleware3 middleware-3-param1))
```

both middleware3 and in/prod need handler as parameter. Wrapping middleware3 in parenthesis evaluates without possibility to pass handler as a parameter. Hence I thought a macro is needed. I worked out how to make in/prod a function passing middleware3 and middleware params as parameters:

```
(defn prod [handler middleware & middleware-params]
  (if (= "production" (System/getenv "APP_ENV"))
    (apply middleware handler middleware-params)
    handler))
```

It changes the syntax a bit though. The call looks like:

```
(-> handler
    middleware1
    middleware2
    (in/prod middleware3 middleware-3-param1)
```

How would I go around to being able to use syntax like:

```
(in/prod (middleware3 middleware-3-param1)
```

Comment: I don't see any reason to use a macro here. Can you provide more details as to why this must be a macro and not an `fn` that returns a handler?

Comment: well, maybe not. initially my thinking was that I need macro not to evaluate middleware. it was before I've wrapped it in the function.

ideally I would like to be able not to wrap "airbrake/wrap-airbrake" inside a function, aka have less boilerplate.

Comment: Wouldn't the desired usage be more like: `(in/prod (airbrake/wrap-airbrake handler config/airbrake-api-key))`? With your usage you could simply use a function. And `prod` expects two parameters and you are only passing one, is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You could need this to be a macro iff the middleware you wish to apply is also a macro and thus you are suffering from macro-contagion. In that you would simply want a macro that returns one of two possible s-expressins to be included in the resulting code. One where handler is called directly and one where it is wrapped in the given middleware.

```
(defmacro prod [handler middleware]
  (if (= "production" (System/getenv "APP_ENV"))
    `(~middleware ~handler) ;; or (list middleware handler)
     handler))
```

If you are not currently suffering from macro-contagion while unable to fix that by removing the macro elsewhere, then you do not need to use such a macro and the code in your example can simply be used as a function rather than as a macro. The empty-middlware bit is not required in either case.

Comment: Indeed the implementation of `empty-middleware` is simply a more restrictive version of `identity`.